# Why do I get an "inherited platform declaration clash" error in a derived class?

Tags: android, kotlin, derived-class

Having an interface (defined from a dependent SDK and cannot making change, the BaseDelegate is from the sdk as well) and a base class:

```
interface ViewDelegate {

    fun getDataType() : String
    fun getItemViewType() : Int

    fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup): RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, item: Data, position: Int)

    fun getClickHandler() : View.OnClickListener
    fun setClickHandler(clickHanlder: View.OnClickListener)
}

open class BaseDelegate(@JvmField var clickHandler: View.OnClickListener) : ViewDelegate {

    @JvmField var layoutId = R.layout.base_view

    override fun getClickHandler(): View.OnClickListener {
        return clickHandler
    }

    override fun setClickHandler(clickHanlder: View.OnClickListener) {
        clickHandler = clickHanlder
    }

    override fun getDataType(): String {
        return "Base_TYPE"
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(): Int {
        return 1000
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return BaseViewHolder(parent.inflate(layoutId, false), clickHandler)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, item: IData, position: Int) {
        (holder as? BaseViewHolder)?.bindView(item, position)
    }
}
```

It is fine.

But if making a derived class from the base one, it gets error

```
class DerivedViewDelegate(clickHandler: View.OnClickListener) : BaseDelegate(clickHandler){

    init {
        layoutId = R.layout.child_view
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        val vw = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(layoutId, parent, false)
        return ChildViewHolder(vw, clickHandler)
    }
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, item: Data, position: Int) {
        (holder as? ChildViewHolder)?.bindView(item, position)
    }
}
```

The error says:

```
inherited platform declaration clash: The following declarations have same JVM signature (getClickHandler()Landroid/view$OnClickListner;)  fun <get-clickHandler>(): View.OnClickListener defined in DerivedViewDelegate fun getClickHandler(): View.OnClickListener defined in DerivedViewDelegate

inherited platform declaration clash: The following declarations have same JVM signature (setClickHandler(Landroid/view$OnClickListner;)V)  fun <set-clickHandler>(<set-?>: View.OnClickListener): Unit  defined in DerivedViewDelegate fun setClickHandler(clickHandler: View.OnClickListener): Unit defined in DerivedViewDelegate
```

In Java it is fine:

```
class DerivedViewDelegate extends BaseDelegate {

    public DerivedViewDelegate(View.OnClickListener clickHandler) {
            super(clickHandler);
            layoutId = R.layout.child_view;
        }
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, Data item, int position) {
            ((ChildViewHolder )holder).onBindViewHolder(item, position);
}

@NotNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent) {

    View vw = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(layoutId, parent, false);
    return new ChildViewHolder(vw, clickHandler);

}
}
```

Comment: Add the `@JvmField` annotation to the `clickHandler` in your constructor, or rename it.

Comment: @TheWnaderer,  class DerivedViewDelegate(@JvmField clickHandler2: View.OnClickListener) : BaseDelegate(clickHandler2)  does not work, same error

Answer (score 1):

The main problem becomes visible if you remove `@JvmField`; if you remove it from BaseDelegate, you get the same error there.

What's happening is the field creates its own getters and setters, which conflict with the methods in the parent class. Using @JvmField on the derived class doesn't work; it still shows the same error.

So, instead of declaring getters and setters, there's a relatively easy solution. Interfaces in Kotlin can have fields. Kind of anyways, they get compiled to getters and setters from what I can tell. Anyways, the main point is that it allows for an easy way to deal with required variables in interfaces.

So, change your interface to this:

```
interface ViewDelegate {
    var clickHandler: View.OnClickListener

    fun getDataType() : String
    fun getItemViewType() : Int

    fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup): RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, data: ClipData.Item, position: Int)

}
```

Notice that I removed the getters and setters, and just replaced it with a variable instead.

Now, in the BaseDelegate class, you have to override the variable:

```
class BaseDelegate(override var clickHandler: View.OnClickListener) : ViewDelegate
```

@JvmField is gone. Also remember to remove your getter and setter in the class, you won't need them any more. Once you've removed @JvmField, the getter and setter in BaseDelegate and in ViewDelegate, in addition to adding the field, it should compile.

---

Since you can't change the interface (which is the best option you have btw), there is another option. Private fields don't use getters and setters unless they're explicitly defined. Take this example:

```
class Test(){
    var x: Int = 0
    fun something(){
        x = 3
    }
}
```

It compiles to:

```
public final class Test {
   private int x;

   public final int getX() {
      return this.x;
   }

   public final void setX(int var1) {
      this.x = var1;
   }

   public final void something() {
      this.x = 3;
   }
}
```

Notice how x is referenced directly. Now, if I make it private:

```
class Test(){
    private var x: Int = 0
    fun something(){
        x = 3
    }
}
```

This happens:

```
public final class Test {
   private int x;

   public final void something() {
      this.x = 3;
   }
}
```

The getter and setter is gone. However, if I explicitly declare them:

```
class Test(){
    private var x: Int = 0
        get() = field
        set(v) {
            field = v;
        }
    fun something(){
        x = 3
    }
}
```

It produces:

```
public final class Test {
   private int x;

   private final int getX() {
      return this.x;
   }

   private final void setX(int v) {
      this.x = v;
   }

   public final void something() {
      this.setX(3);
   }
}
```

The same happens with a public var; if the getter is declared and it's custom (not just `get set`), it uses `.setX(v)` instead of `this.x = v`.

How does this apply to your situation?

You have clashing declarations of a generated getter and a getter declared by a library. So, since private fields don't create a getter and/or setter unless one is explicitly defined, change your var to be private:

```
open class BaseDelegate(private var clickHandler: View.OnClickListener) : ViewDelegate
```

***Note that this breaks property access syntax;*** you will not be able to call `derivedViewDelegateInst.clickHandler`, and you'll need to use the getter, even in Kotlin.

Comment: thanks Zoe, but cannot make change to the interface, it from other lib.

Comment: I'll see if I can find another alternative then.

Comment: Is the library written in Kotlin originally?

Comment: yes, the baseDelegate is actually from the sdk as well,  just want to override it.  I guess the @JvmField is there for Java app to override it.

Comment: a 3rd part library (i call it sdk, not android library/sdk)

Comment: I am highly aware, and I'm not asking if it's the android SDK or not; I'm asking which library/framework/sdk/whatever you wanna call it you're using

Comment: sorry, these are the sdk/lib config the app is using:

compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion “28.0.2” 

"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:12.6.1”

Comment: I can't find view delegate in the Kotlin stdlib

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180458/discussion-between-zoe-and-lannyf).